# Having trouble installing WinSCP PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, winscp-net, powershell-module

I'm trying to use the [WinSCP PowerShell module](http://dotps1.github.io/WinSCP/) on a Windows 7 system. This is what I've done:

1. Installed Windows PowerShell version 5.0.
2. Installed Windows Management Framwork v5.0
3. Started PowerShell as Administrator
4. Executed command `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
5. Executed command `Install-Module -Name WinSCP` (which result in no output).
6. Selected `Yes` when asked to download and install `NuGet-anycpu.exe`

Finally, I did a sanity check by executing command `Open-WinSCPSession`, which results in the following error:

```
  The term 'Open-WinSCPSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
  function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
  name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
  again.
  At line:1 char:1

+ Open-WinSCPSession
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Open-WinSCPSession:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This suggests that the module did not install correctly. Any suggestions as to what I've done wrong?

Comment: Does `Install-Module -Name WinSCP` always ask you to install `NuGet-anycpu.exe`?

Comment: I just tried running command. It waits for a while then no output at all - it doesn't ask to install NuGet.

Comment: Fair enough, what I was trying to find out, was if OneGet is broken. (I have not been able to get OneGet working in multiple PCs...) Can you install other packages?